# Как прогонять все запросы на сервер сайта через один определенный скрипт?

Tags: php, apache, сервер

Имеется сайт с сервером Apache и обработчиком php. Нужно, чтобы все запросы к серверу, кроме js и css файлов, (т.е. все страницы, изображения и ajax запросы) проходили через определенный php скрипт-контроллер, который сам определит дальнейшее поведение и выходные данные. При этом в адресной строке браузера ничего не меняется, скрипт-контроллер знает, что было в адресной строке, и запрос не зависит от файлов на сервере (т.е. по запросу http://домен/поддомен/документ ни папки "поддомен", ни файла "документ" может не существовать).
Я не знаю, возможно ли это вообще так, как я описал, но может есть что-то похожее или другие пути реализации этого.
Задача, как я понял, сложная (или я тупой), так что спасибо)

Comment: Ну очень сложная задача. по запросу PHP ЧПУ найдется примерно миллион ответов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это елементарная задача для PHP.

Сначала нужно перенаправить через .htaccess запросы на обработчик.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Строка `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` значит, что если файл на сервере существует - запрос не перенаправляем.
Так же можно добавить аналогичную строку с `!-d`, которая действует так же, но для папок.

Далее на PHP уже получаем запрос и делаем с ним что захотим.

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if(...){
  ...
}
```

---

Подробнее по вашему вопросу можно почитать, загуглив `php единая точка входа` или `php чпу`.

---

Так же можно просто переименовывать папки или менять маршрутизацию через .htaccess.

Например, следующий код уберет расширения `.php` у файлов, то есть к файлу `site.com/test.php` можно обращатся просто `site.com/test`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Остальные примеры можно с легкостью нагуглить.